# best approach to call entries from two different sections

Tags: sections

I have set up two sections for two different kinds of events. On one page I want to differentiate between them on the other page I want to list them all. How do I organise that best on the back end and how do I call it best in the template?

1. big events
2. small events
3. overview for all events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one section called `events` with the different [entryTypes](https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries#entry-types) `small` and `big`.

You'll fetch all events with

```
craft.entries.section('events')
```

when you want to fetch only small events you'll do

```
craft.entries.section('events').type('small')
```

and the same for the big one.

However you can call entries from multiple sections too

```
craft.entries.section(['smallEvents', 'bigEvents'])
```

I suggest you to read the [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries) these [Cheet Sheets](https://straightupcraft.com/articles/cheat-sheet-craft.entries) are a good place to learn templating too

Comment: Thanks Robin! You are always very helpful! I find the multiple sections approach easier for the editor differentiate between the kinds of events.